# MongoDB $and operator query in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

I've been having difficulty with the $and operator and MongoRegex.

I'm doing a regex record search for "Amazon" that also has the field "enabled" set to 1.

This is my query.

```
$search = "Amazon";
$results = $collection->find(array(
  '$and' => array(
     array('orgname' => new MongoRegex("/.*$search.*/")),
     array('enabled' => '1')
   )
));
```

Maybe someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I edited your question and formatted in so it is easier to read. Perhaps it works now. I think you hade placed one ending bracket at the end instead of after  `new MongoRegex("/.*$search.*/")`. But I cannot go back and see your orignal post... Anyway, in this case you don't need the `$and` operator, see my anwer.

Comment: @luttkens If you changed the code then you changed the nature of the question, that incorrect bracket could have been the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in this case you don't need to use the `$and` operator. Try this:

```
$search = "Amazon";
$cursor = $collection->find(array(
  'orgname' =>new MongoRegex("/.$search./"), 
  'enabled' => 1)
);
```